# AWS Step function use input value to make complete command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions

How can use input in my state machine in mid of a string?

For example, I want to make a command using input params like this

```
["python test.py", "--name=$.name", "--age=$.age"]
```

But as per AWS documentation, I can't pass like above. I can only pass like

```json
{"Command.$": "$.age"}
```

Why this strange structure is required. Why do I need to use `.$` in the key. Why can't I use `$.age` freely anywhere?

What I want to achieve is something like this.

```json
{
    "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
    "StartAt": "Pipeline",
    "States": {
        "Run Pipeline": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "Parameters": {
                "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
                "Cluster": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "TaskDefinition": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "Overrides": {
                    "ContainerOverrides": [{
                        "Name": "my_container",
                        "Command": [
                            "python test.py",
                            "--name=$.name",
                            "--age=$.age"
                        ]
                    }]
                }
            },
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```

where my step function input is

```json
{"name": "Rahul", "age": 25}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.$` tells step-functions that you are passing a path and not a literal string value.

[Input/Ouput Path Params Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html)

If you want to construct a string from inputs, you should be able to use intrinsic string formatting:

`States.Format('python test.py --name={} --age={}', $.name, $.age)`

[Intrinsic Function Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html)

```json
{
    "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
    "StartAt": "Run Pipeline",
    "States": {
        "Run Pipeline": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "Parameters": {
                "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
                "Cluster": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "TaskDefinition": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "Overrides": {
                    "ContainerOverrides": [{
                        "Name": "my_container",
                        "Command.$": "States.Array(States.Format('python test.py --name={} --age={}', $.name, $.age))"
                    }]
                }
            },
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```

`States.Array` makes an array out of a list of inputs.

`States.Format` lets you construct a string using literal and interpolated (variable) inputs.

Comment: I got the Below error?


```
There are Amazon States Language errors in your state machine definition. Fix the errors to continue.
Cannot construct instance of `java.util.ArrayList` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('States.Array(States.Format('python test.py --name={} --age={}', $.name, $.age))') (at /States/VideoPersonalizationFargateTask/Parameters)
For more information, see Amazon States Language.
```